# Is it possible for i3 to hard-set full-screen size?

Tags: i3, tiling-wm, fullscreen

Often times with applications full-screen mode does exactly what I want, cutting out optional items (like URL bars, bookmarks, play/pause buttons, status bars, menu bars, etc). The problem is the size isn't constrained to anything and takes the whole screen. Can i3 trick the window into composing it with something like picture-in-picture where the window takes up the whole tile in file screen mode but does not take up the whole screen?

I would like to open up VLC and Chrome and hit "F11" and have the window constraints to area I designate with i3.

If this isn't possible with i3, is it possible with any tiling window manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fullscreen toggle` command should do what you want, but only if you use it after you go full-screen in the app. I believe it's bound to <kbd>$mod</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in the default (QWERTY) configuration file that `i3-config-wizard` generates.

Comment: That takes up the whole screen. That's exactly what I don't. I don't want a single-window workspace. I want to abuse the applications full-screen mode (which drops window elements) inside a split or floating window in i3.

Comment: What if you activate the application's full screen mode and then press mod+f? For me, that does what I think you want (keeps the application in full-screen but constrains it to a window you can tile as normal), at least for Chrome.

Comment: yep, that does it! That's the key there go full-screen in the app and then in the program. Please update the program to reflect that, it does something totally than `$mod+f`` outside full screen mode.